# luigi batch module used in is straight batch Tasks

Tags: python, parallel-processing, luigi

I have 500 links to download and want to batch them by for example 10 items.

How this pseudo code would be like?

```
class BatchJobTask(luigi.Task)
    items = luigi.Parameter()
    def run(self):
        listURLs = []
        with ('urls_chunk', 'r') as urls
            for line in urls:
                listURLs.append('http://ggg'+line+'.org')
            10_urls = listURLs[0:items] #10 items here
            for i in 10_urls:
                req = request.get(url)
                req.contents
    def output(self):
        return self.LocalTarger("downloaded_filelist.txt")

class BatchWorker(luigi.Task)
    def run(self)
        # Here I should run BatchJobTask from 0 to 10, next 11 - 21 new etc...
```

How it would be?

Comment: where is your list of urls?

Comment: I have updated first post

Comment: I meant where is this list of urls stored? In a queue, a database, a file? What you have to do is figure out how many are in that thing and then build up your chunks from there. I'll make an example below, but it is unlikely to be relevant to your problem as you have not specified the relevant parts of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach to doing something like what you want, but with the list of strings stored as separate lines in a file.

```
import luigi
import requests

BATCH_SIZE = 10


class BatchProcessor(luigi.Task):
    items = luigi.ListParameter()
    max = luigi.IntParameter()

    def requires(self):
        return None

    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget('processed'+str(max)+'.txt')

    def run(self):
        for item in self.items:
            req = requests.get('http://www.'+item+'.org')
            # do something useful here
            req.contents
        open("processed"+str(max)+".txt",'w').close()


class BatchCreator(luigi.Task):
    file_with_urls = luigi.Parameter()

    def requires(self):
        required_tasks = []
        f = open(self.file_with_urls)
        batch_index = 0
        total_index = 0
        lines = []
        while True:
            line = f.readline()
            if not line: break
            total_index += 1
            if batch_index < BATCH_SIZE:
                lines.append(line)
                batch_index += 1
            else:
                required_tasks.append(BatchProcessor(batch=lines))
                lines = [line]
                batch_index = 1
        return required_tasks

    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget(str(self.file_with_urls) + 'processed')

    def run(self):
        open(str(self.file_with_urls) + 'processed', 'w').close()
```

Comment: Don't use `max` as a variable in python. Also, you need to refer to `self.max` to get the local parameter value; this code won't run.

Answer (score 1):

I did this.

```
class GetListtask(luigi.Task)
    def run(self):
        ...
    def output(self):
    return luigi.LocalTarget(self.outputfile)

class GetJustOneFile(luigi.Task):
    fid = luigi.IntParameter()
    def requires(self):
        pass

    def run(self):
        url = 'http://my-server.com/test' + str(self.fid) + '.txt'
        download_file = requests.get(url, stream=True)
        with self.output().open('w') as downloaded_file:
            downloaded_file.write(str(download_file.content))

    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget("test{}.txt".format(self.fid))


class GetAllFiles(luigi.WrapperTask):
    def requires(self):
        listoffiles = []  # 0..999
        for i in range(899):
            listoffiles.append(i)
        return [GetJustOneFile(fid=fileid) for fileid in listoffiles]
```

Does this code awful?

Comment: Well, it doesn't do the batching, but it should work.

Comment: How can I input file from GetListTask in GetAllFiles instead of predefined list?

Comment: That's what I showed in the `requires` method of my `BatchCreator` task, assuming you have a file where each line of the file is the varying URN component.